# Loading large amount data from MS SQL to datatables taking long time

Tags: javascript, sql, datatable

I am trying to load data fast and used javascript and sql query below. But it is very slow loading.

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[Proc_LoadAllVehicles2]
as
Declare @DisplayLength int
SET  @DisplayLength =5000

Declare @DisplayStart int
SET @DisplayStart = 0

Declare @Search nvarchar(100)
SET @Search  =  ''

Declare @SortCol int
SET @SortCol  =  ''

Declare @SortDirec nvarchar(100)
SET @SortDirec  =  ''

Declare @FirstRecord int ,@LastRecord int
set @FirstRecord = @DisplayStart;
set @LastRecord = @DisplayStart + @DisplayLength;

With t_Vehicle_Detail
as
(

Select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Vehicle_Detail.Serial_no DESC)            
as  RowNum

FROM Vehicle_Detail  

  where ( @Search LIKE  '%'+@Search+'%'  )

)

 SELECT  * FROM     t_Vehicle_Detail where   RowNum>@FirstRecord  and  RowNum <=  @LastRecord
```

and

```
function LoadAllTrucksList() {

    debugger;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Trucks.asmx/LoadAllTrucksList",
        data: '{}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        datatype: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            var obj = (typeof response.d) == 'string' ? eval('(' + response.d + ')') : response.d;
            if (obj.retCode == 1) {

                debugger
                Arr = obj.dtTable;

                var ul = '';
                //$("#tbl_Detail").empty();
                // var ToatlDueAmount = 0;
                //$("#LocationDetails").empty();
                for (var i = 0; i < Arr.length; i++) {

                    ul += '<tr class="odd">';
                    //ul += '<td class=" ">' + parseInt(i + 1) + '</td>';
                    ul += '<td class=" " style="vertical-align: top;min-width:100px;"><small>' + Arr[i].Vehicle_no + '</small></td>';
                    ul += '<td class=" "><small>' + Arr[i].Loading_Date + '</small></td>';
                    ul += '<td class=" "><small>' + Arr[i].Unloading_Date + '</small></td>';
                    ul += '<td class=" "><small>' + Arr[i].Weight + '</small></td>';
                    ul += '<td class=" "><small>' + Arr[i].Rate + '</small></td>';
                    ul += '<td class=" "><small>' + Arr[i].FrieghtAmount + '</small></td>';
                    ul += '<td class=" "><small>' + Arr[i].Advance + '</small></td>';
                    ul += '<td class=" "><small>' + Arr[i].Balance + '</small></td>';
                    ul += '<td class=" "><small>' + Arr[i].FromCity + '</small></td>';
                    ul += '<td class=" "><small>' + Arr[i].ToCity + '</small></td>';
                    ul += '<td class=" "><small>' + Arr[i].Material + '</small></td>';
                    ul += '<td class=" "><small>' + Arr[i].Party + '</small></td>';
                    ul += '<td class=" "><small>' + Arr[i].Owner + '</small></td>';
                    ul += '<td class=" "><small>' + Arr[i].DriverName + '</small></td>';
                    ul += '<td class=" "><small>' + Arr[i].Remarks + '</small></td>';

                    ul += '<td class=" "><a class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" style="cursor:pointer" title="Edit" href="EditTrucksDetails.aspx?Regiud=' + Arr[i].Serial_no + '"></a></td> '

                    //ul += '<td class=" ">' + Arr[i].ContactNo + '</td>';
                    //ul += '<td class=" ">' + Arr[i].NoOfInfants + '</td>';

                    // ul += '<td class=" "><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" style="cursor:pointer" title="Delete"  onclick="Delete(' + Arr[i].nID + ')"></span></td>';
                    ul += '</tr>';

                }
                $("#tbl_Detail tbody").empty();
                $("#tbl_Detail tbody").append(ul);
                $("#tbl_Detail").dataTable({
                    "bSort": false,
                    "processing": true, // control the processing indicator.
                    "serverSide": true, // recommended to use serverSide when data is more than 10000 rows for performance reasons
                    "info": true,   // control table information display field
                    "stateSave": true,  //restore table state on page reload,
                    "lengthMenu": [[10, 20, 50, -1], [10, 20, 50, "All"]],
                    "dataSrc": ""
                });
                document.getElementById("tbl_Detail");
            }
            else if (obj.retCode == 0) {
                $("#tbl_Detail").empty();
                ul += '<tr>';
                ul += '<td colspan="5">No Record Found</td>'
                ul += '</tr>';
                $('#tbl_Detail').append(ul);
            }
            // $('#tbl_Detail tbody').append(ul);





        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `@Search` is always going to be `LIKE %@Search%`

Comment: Which piece is taking a long time? Pulling the data from the database to C#? Sending the data a thousand miles from your servers to a user across the US/Europe? Loading the data into your HTML table with your JavaScript?